# How to update StateFlow inside the ViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow, android-compose

I have this employee list in my composable:

```
val employeeViewModel: EmployeeViewModel = viewModel()
val employeeState by employeeViewModel.employeeState.collectAsState(ViewResult.Loading)

ALlEmployees(employeeState = employeeState,
      onRefresh = {
         // TODO: Re-fetch the list
      })
```

And this is my viewModel

```
var employeeState: StateFlow<ViewResult<List<Employee>>> = fetchEmployeesUseCase().stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
            initialValue = ViewResult.Loading,
        )
private set
```

I am really not sure how can I refetch the employee list. The flow needs to be re-trigerred somehow. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you wanna update you `employeeState` from the lamba `onRefresh`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I just published the code that can help you, check it out

Answer (score 1):

Well, to achieve this let's start by refactoring the viewModel.
The way I always handle it is this:

```
class EmployeeViewModel(
    private val repository: TestRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    // Here we store the value of the employee list status
    // We have the internal mutable state '_uiEmployeeState' and the public state 'uiEmployeeState'
    // The public state will be used in the composable to obtain the state value safely
    private val uiEmployeeState = MutableStateFlow<ViewResult<List<Employee>>>(ViewResult.Loading)
    val _uiEmployeeState: StateFlow<ViewResult<List<Employee>>> = uiEmployeeState

    // Use this function if you want the state to be updated every time the viewmodel is instantiated.
    init {
        fetchEmployees()
    }

    /**
     * Function that is responsible for updating the employee state
     *  - Use a 'viewModelScope' if the function is suspend, otherwise do it directly
     *  - Use 'update' to update the state value, you can also use '.value'
     *  - Use 'first' to get the first value of the flow and update the state
     */
    fun fetchEmployees() {
        uiEmployeeState.value = ViewResult.Loading
        viewModelScope.launch {
            uiEmployeeState.update {
                repository.fetchEmployeesUseCase().first()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In the viewModel insider the `fetchEmployees()` you could set temporary the state as `loading`, that in case you have some animation or something like that, otherwise you can omit it and directly update the state.
Also in my example we get the data from a repository, you can change it to your useCase

And on the part of the UI it would be like this:

```
val employeeViewModel: EmployeeViewModel = viewModel()
// You do not need to give it the initial value since the viewModel already has one
val employeeState by employeeViewModel._uiEmployeeState.collectAsState()

AllEmployees(
    employeeState = employeeState,
    onRefresh = { employeeViewModel.fetchEmployees() }
     // You can also use it as a lambda reference
    //onRefresh = employeeViewModel::fetchEmployees

)
```

Also as recommendation when you heard an state from the viewModel, you could check the library that is recommended:

-> `collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`

It only collects values from a Flow or StateFLow in a lifecycle-aware manner, allowing your app to save unneeded app resources. Specially for cases where you use StateFlow

Here I give you a link of reference:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state?hl=es-419#use-other-types-of-state-in-jetpack-compose